# apache tomcat7 throws error after starting server

Tags: java, server, tomcat7

when I am adding server in eclipse and run getting error like "Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)." and also changed port number in sever.xml to 8080 to 8085 but still getting the same error and still localhost:8080 showing welcome page.

Plase help me on this issue.

Comment: _To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)._ - what exactly is unclear? If localhost:8080 shows the welcome page, maybe your server is indeed already running?

Comment: What is the OS platform You use? OSX, Windows, Linux???

Comment: Did you check that previous attempts to start the server are stopped?

Comment: I am using windows 64 bit system.now I am getting below error,

Comment: Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @Marvin..I never able to start server

Answer (score 0):

That means some of ports (8005, 8080, 8009) is already use by some other process. to solve this problem you have to stop that process or you can change your tomcat ports to other port like 8090,8091, 8092 etc.

for ubuntu :-

command for check process and ports : `sudo netstat -tupln`

kill process :- `kill -9 4469`

Comment: I have changed all ports to different port number still sever throwing error unable to start.I am using eclipse neon and apache tomcat 7 in windows 64 bit system

Comment: now I am getting Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)